# mplleaflet in Jupyter - avoid whitespace with notebook mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib, leaflet, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

mplleaflet works great with '%matplotlib inline' mode in the Jupyter Notebook, but when enabling '%matplotilib notebook' mode, there's a big chunk of whitespace between the cell and the map. Can this be avoided?

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet

%matplotlib notebook

#some latitudes bracketing seattle
lats = [47.5062,47.7062]
#longitude
lons = [-122.3321]*len(lats)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.scatter(lons, lats, alpha=0) #invisible data points, just to scale the map

mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is a figure created which is supposed to be shown in the notebook. However, you do not want to show the mplleaflet figure as an interactive figure with the `%matplotlib notebook` backend.

One idea is to not use the `%matplotlib notebook` such that the area where the figure mplleaflet figure would be placed is not filled with the unused figure.

[image]

Alternatively use `%%capture` in order to suppress the output when using `%matplotlib notebook`. Then call `mplleaflet.display` in a new non-captured cell:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The capture suggestion is a nice solution.